# BootStrap Year range

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to specify range between two datepicker. `from` and `to` which look like following
[image]

In above image I selected `from year` as 2011 and now I do not want to select `to year` is less than from year. How can achieve this.

**Code**

```
$('#from').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy",
        autoclose: true,
        minViewMode: "years"
});

$('#to').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy",
        autoclose: true,
        minViewMode: "years"
});
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLe0yhz5/)**

Comment: @TusharGupta I added fiddle please check it

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21438647/bootstrap-datepicker-disable-past-dates-after-first-date-field-is-set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hLe0yhz5/1/)

Code

```
$('#from').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy",
        autoclose: true,
        minViewMode: "years"
})    .on('changeDate', function(selected){
        startDate =  $("#from").val();
        $('#to').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
    }); 
;


$('#to').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy",
        autoclose: true,
        minViewMode: "years"
});
```

See

```
 on('changeDate', function(selected){
     startDate =  $("#from").val();
     $('#to').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
});
```

Logic:

Here after i select From year ,I set its minimum Year set by From Datepicker using `$('#to').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);`
.

Comment: Please paste your fiddle code in answer so easily user can see your code.

Answer (score 0):

since this is a common problem there are many posts about this problem so far.
Most of them are nearly exact the same as yours.

you can check this one for example its also written with ajax / jQuery
[jQuery Date Picker - disable past dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356358/jquery-date-picker-disable-past-dates)

this one is espacialy about disabling past dates on the datepicker:
[disable past dates on datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757918/disable-past-dates-on-datepicker)

so its more or less duplicated question where you can get a fix to this problem from already asked questions.

See the API for further information about the minDate:
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

i guess a fix check would be to set the minDate something like this (credits to Dasun who wrote this piece of Code in the link given above)

```
minDate: dateToday Or minDate: '0' is the key here. Try to set the minDate property.

$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            minDate: dateToday // minDate: '0' would work too
        });
});
```

Comment: I have two datepicker `from` and `to`. I want range between that two datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sw47L4c4/)

You just neet to specify your 'from' datepicker's onSelect propery:

```
onSelect: function(){
    $('#to').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date($(this).datepicker("getDate").getFullYear(),0,1));       
}
```

Comment: THIS IS JQUERY CALENDER USER WANTS BOOOTSTRAP