# Bootstrap datepicker: Disable past date after first is set

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

How can I disable past dates after first date is selected?

I already tried this solution but it didn't work: [This is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21438647/bootstrap-datepicker-disable-past-dates-after-first-date-field-is-set)

My code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/k5zookLt)

```
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

var checkin = $('.form-control-1').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    minViewMode: 1,
    format: 'mm/yyyy'

}).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.datepicker("getDate").valueOf() || !checkout.datepicker("getDate").valueOf()) {

        var newDate = new Date(ev.date);
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
        checkout.datepicker("update", newDate);

    }
    $('.form-control-2')[0].focus();
});


var checkout = $('.form-control-2').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        if (!checkin.datepicker("getDate").valueOf()) {
            return date.valueOf() >= new Date().valueOf();
        } else {
            return date.valueOf() > checkin.datepicker("getDate").valueOf();
        }
    },
    autoclose: true,
    minViewMode: 1,
    format: 'mm/yyyy'

}).on('changeDate', function (ev) {});
```

Comment: [What about something that already has this built in?](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker)

Comment: Coming from experience, use JQuery UI's datepicker. The bootstrap one may look good, but it isn't maintained well. The UI one has this functionality built in and there is CSS to make it look like the bootstrap items.  https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Comment: It needs to be a monthpicker. I already tried the jquery UI datepicker - http://jsfiddle.net/a3u68d20/12/ but how can I set to display months and years only just like the bootstrap one?

Comment: This is the closest solution I found however it's still not working properly =( http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/k5zookLt/20/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying and trying I finally got a solution for this so I am sharing here in case someone also need this:

**[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/k5zookLt/)**

```
$( ".line" ).each(function(index, element) {

  var startDate = new Date();
  var fechaFin = new Date();
  var FromEndDate = new Date(); 
  var ToEndDate = new Date();

  /* Find 'From' */  
  $(this).find(".form-control-1").addClass("from"+index);

  /* Find 'To' */ 
  $(this).find(".form-control-2").addClass("to"+index);


   $(".from"+index).datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    minViewMode: 1,
    format: 'mm/yyyy'
}).on('changeDate', function(selected){
        startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
        $('.to'+index).datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
    }); 

$('.to'+index).datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    minViewMode: 1,
    format: 'mm/yyyy'
}).on('changeDate', function(selected){
        FromEndDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        FromEndDate.setDate(FromEndDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
        $('.from'+index).datepicker('setEndDate', FromEndDate);
    });  

});
```